# Angular2 - All exceptions originated in error_handler.js and Zone.js

Tags: javascript, angular

We are working on an Angular2 app and are facing an issue that makes debugging errors quite hard. The console logs all exceptions as originated in error_handler.js and Zone.js and the stacktrace shows everything but the real origination of the exception.

Here is a sample of such an exception: 
[image]

[image]

I tried with the [Angular2 Quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) as well as the [WebPack starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). Both have the same behavior. Is there any possibility to improve the debug experience (have the correct origin shown in the console, find it through some debugging tools, everything that helps locating the origin of an exception would make our live easier)?